# How to, using an Eclipse Core Expression, evaluate to true if a given java property is set?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm in need of a way to either show or hide a menu item (using `visibleWhen`) based on whether a -Dxyz is set or not through the command line.

I've googled up but I can't seem to find any relevant information regarding this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`systemTest` tests the value of values from `System.getProperty`

```
<systemTest property="xyz" value="xxx"/>
```